# About two different proofs of Archimedean property

Tags: proof-explanation, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

I've seen two different proofs of Archimedean property:

**$\boxed{(1)}$**

> For every $r∈ℝ$ there exist $n∈ℕ^+$, such that: $n>r$
>
> Proof:
>
> There are two cases to consider, the case where $r\le0$ and the case where $r>0$.
>
> For the first one let $n∈ℕ^+$ and the result follows, for the second one let $n\le r$, then clearly the
> set of all these $n$'s is not empty , also since the set $ℕ$ is bounded above by $r$ and $ℕ⊂ℝ$ using
> Completeness axiom implies sup$ℕ$ exist, denote it by $α$, then clearly $α-1$ is not an upper bound
> for the set $ℕ$, which means: $$∃ \thinspace m∈ℕ:α-1< m$$
> or equivalently :$$∃ \thinspace m∈ℕ:α< (m+1) ∈ℕ$$
> which is a contradiction based on the definition of sup$ℕ=α$, hence the property is true.

**$\boxed{(2)}$**

> For every real number $y$ there exist $ x∈ℝ^+$ and $n∈ℕ^+$ such that: $nx>y$
>
> Proof:
>
> There are two cases to consider, the case where $y\le0$ and the case where $y>0$.
>
> For the first one let $n∈ℕ^+$ and the result follows, for the second one let $nx\le y$, then clearly the
> set of all these $ny$'s denoted $A$ is not empty , also since the set $A$ is bounded above by $y$ and
> $A⊂ℝ$, using Completeness axiom implies sup$A$ exist, denote it by $α$ ,then since $ x∈ℝ^+$ the
> inequality $α-x\leα$ holds , it can be concluded that $α-x$ is not an upper bound for the set $A$, means:
> $$∃ \thinspace m x∈A:α-x< mx$$ or equivalently :$$∃ \thinspace m x∈A:α< (1+m)x ∈A$$ which is a
> contradiction based on the definition of sup$A=α$, hence the property is true.

I think the first proof is actually a special case of the second one when $x=1$, also in the first proof we
claim that for every real number there exist a natural number greater than that, but in the second proof
since $ x∈ℝ^+$ and $n∈ℕ^+$ , implies $nx∈ℝ^+$ , here we actually claim that for every real number
there exist another real number greater than that, this real number is not necessarily natural (non-zero)
, so based on these two reasons I think the second case is a generalized case of the other one, but I'm
not sure if I'm right or not.

Comment: the second case is indeed an (apparent) generalization of the first, and it **should be correctly formulated as** ''for every $x>0$ and arbitrary $y \in \mathbb{R}$ there will exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $nx>y$''. The two claims are equivalent, the first one being a clear particularisation of the first, exactly as you remarked, and the second one being reductible to the first by virtue of the equivalence between $nx>y$ and $n>\frac{y}{x}$ (since $x$ is strictly positive and multiplication by $\frac{1}{x}>0$ preserves inequalities).

Comment: @ΑΘΩ You probably did not intend to say "the first one being a clear particularisation of the first"

Comment: @ΑΘΩ,I think using  notation $\mathbb N$ is indeed more general than $\mathbb N^+$, however choosing such $n$ where $n$ is a natural number according to our usage in the proof is equivalent to choosing such $n$ from the set of positive natural numbers ( I start natural numbers from $0$),so your notation and mine both have the same application in the proof.

Comment: @Henry: I certainly did not, alas the comment section can no longer be edited, so may I post a brief errata over here: **the first one being a particularisation of the second**.

Comment: @Absurd: indeed it is not difficult to show that the claims as they are formulated with $n$ taken generally from $\mathbb{N}$ are equivalent to the (apparently) stronger claims where one requires $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}=\mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$. Not only are you doing well to start natural numbers from $0$, it would be quite preposterous and severely handicapped to ''start'' them from anywhere else (as though $0$ weren't itself worthy of being considered a finite cardinal which it very much is).